Issues with installing Linux on a laptop
So, I recently bought a new laptop (HP 15-fd0083wm) and I tried to install Linux on it, but it never works, it says it can't find the UUID for root, but when I check fstab, they match. The issue with this laptop is that there is no way that I've found in the BIOS to enable legacy mode, or ahci. I hope I didn't just buy an expensive paperweight.
Basically, I dont know what I did, but its unbootable, I am able to get into grub, but when initramfs loads, it cannot detect my drive. it just says its missing, its not there when you do ls /dev or blkid in the shell.
The question I have is: How do I get this working?
The distros I've tried so far are: Ubuntu, Debian, Mint, Pop os, and Arch.

what is your question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

What distro(s) have you tried?   When yo say you have checked fstab and they match - how did you check it?  Are you getting to grub?   (If you can get to grub, its not a paperweight)

I am able to get to grub, or some boot manager, theres a couple options, efi file boot, linux boot manager, and windows boot manager (which seems to keep reviving itself from death)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your laptop uses UFS (Universal Flash Storage).
I have no experience with this.
Look here for example:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1446115/install-ubuntu-22-10-on-the-computer-with-ufs-universal-flash-storage-showing-t

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Welcome to Super User!
A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it. Add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.  See also, Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?.

This unfortunately did not work for me, maybe its not worked for me yet. Still trying!
